# Move the footer at the bottom of a DT in Shiny R

Tags: shiny, datatables, dt

I have a datatable where the footer has "Previous/Next" text. Currently it is overlapping the "Displaying 1 of 15" text. Is there a way to move this so I dont get an over lap?

Here is a picture as well as the code. I am not very familiar with html/java script so if you could provide an answer explaining why you are using the specific code that would be greatly appreciated

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)
library(DT)


x = data.frame(one = rep("Hey how is everyones day? I need some help on this shiny application and learn how to use some of the features on datatable.", 10),
               two = rep("this is the second column of text. ", 10),
               three = rep("this is the third column of text", 10))


    ui = bs4DashPage(
        old_school = FALSE,
        sidebar_min = TRUE,
        sidebar_collapsed = FALSE,
        controlbar_collapsed = FALSE,
        controlbar_overlay = TRUE,
        title = "Basic Dashboard",
        navbar = bs4DashNavbar(),
        sidebar = bs4DashSidebar(),
        controlbar = bs4DashControlbar(),
        footer = bs4DashFooter(),
        body = bs4DashBody(
            DTOutput("table")
        )
    )
    
    server = function(input, output) {
        
        output$table = renderDataTable({
            datatable(x, rownames = F, style = "bootstrap",  extensions = 'Responsive', options = list(
                #dom = 't'
            ))
        })
    }


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

When i run the same code on shiny dashboard, it comes out the way I would want it to look like. So i believe it is something to do with Bs4Dash styling sheet. Below is how it looks with shinydashboard

[image]

Comment: Please share an example.

Comment: @ismirsehregal i have updated my post with an example plus the way i would like it to look

Comment: Hi. Let's debug together, and I'll post an answer when we find the problem. Would it fix it to remove `options`? As assigning manually the `#dom = 't'` is possibly breaking the layout. Could you share more about why have you added that option?

Comment: Hi @IslamElshobokshy the options menu is not the problem. However, I did figure something out. It only does not work on start up. My DT displays a data table with information about a specific stock. Once you change the stock (rendering the table again), the issue gets resolved.

Comment: @JordanWrong I see, that's an important information. In that case try to call the draw function after your render. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redraw your table after initialization.

```
$('#tableIdHere').DataTable().draw();
```

Comment: Hey Islam, just trying to understand this before i run. Where are is the input$refresh coming from?

Comment: @JordanWrong I'm not familiar with Shiny as I am with Datatables. You can [read here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.3/observeEvent.html) about how the `observeEvent` works. As for DT, when the table is falsely initialized you always call `.draw()` in order to rearrange that said table.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. I tried adding the above, but i am unable to get it working. I am not too sure why we would be adding observeEvent()

Comment: @JordanWrong as I said, I'm not familiar with shiny but I am familiar with DT. I'm not sure where you should add in shiny the redraw but it needs to be after the first and initial DT rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out , Hope it will sove your problem.

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)
library(DT)


x = data.frame(one = rep("Hey how is everyones day? I need some help on this shiny application and learn how to use some of the features on datatable.", 10),
               two = rep("this is the second column of text. ", 10),
               three = rep("this is the third column of text", 10))


ui = bs4DashPage(
  old_school = FALSE,
  sidebar_min = TRUE,
  sidebar_collapsed = FALSE,
  controlbar_collapsed = FALSE,
  controlbar_overlay = TRUE,
  title = "Basic Dashboard",
  navbar = bs4DashNavbar(),
  #sidebar = bs4DashSidebar(),
  controlbar = bs4DashControlbar(),
  footer = bs4DashFooter(),
  body = bs4DashBody(
    DTOutput("table")
  )
)

server = function(input, output) {
  
  output$table = renderDataTable({
    datatable(x, rownames = F,   extensions = 'Responsive', options = list(
      #dom = 't'
    ))
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have only removed `style = "bootstrap"` from the `renderDataTable` and that serve the perpose

[image: image_app]

Comment: hey Gourab, i would like to keep the bootstrap feature

Answer (score 0):

Your css is overwritten with some other default css. Please check if your classes are similarly named or clashing with each other.

Comment: No, it's Datatables that fails to correctly render on initialization.